# how to run multiple commands on success

Tags: windows, powershell

In bash & CMD you can do `rm not-exists && ls` to string together multiple commands, each running conditionally only if the previous commands succeeded.

In powershell you can do `rm not-exists; ls`, but the `ls` will always run, even when `rm` fails.

How do I easily replicate the functionality (in one line) that bash & CMD do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most errors in Powershell are "Non-terminating" by default, that is, they do not cause your script to cease execution when they are encountered.  That's why `ls` will be executed even after an error in the `rm` command.

You can change this behavior in a couple of ways, though.  You can change it globally via the `$errorActionPreference` variable (e.g. `$errorActionPreference = 'Stop'`), or change it only for a particular command by setting the `-ErrorAction` parameter, which is common to all cmdlets.  This is the approach that makes the most sense for you.

```
# setting ErrorAction to Stop will cause all errors to be "Terminating"
# i.e. execution will halt if an error is encountered
rm 'not-exists' -ErrorAction Stop; ls
```

Or, using some common shorthand

```
rm 'not-exists' -ea 1; ls
```

The `-ErrorAction` parameter is explained the help.  Type `Get-Help about_CommonParameters`

Comment: On second though, I'm going to +1 this. After adding `$errorActionPreference = 'Stop'` to my `$PROFILE` I realized that powershell really isn't that bad. It's actually kind of nice behavior...

Comment: Thank you for this - it helped greatly. If you want this as default functionality, open C:\Users\{username}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\{profile-file}.ps1 and add ```$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'``` there.

Answer (score 0):

To check the exit code from a powershell command you can use `$?`.

For example, the following command will try to remove `not-exists` and if it is successful it will run `ls`.

```
rm not-exists; if($?){ ls }
```

Comment: @latkin's answer is slightly better - only because it's 5 characters instead of 9 characters. Honestly, I don't like either answer and I'd rather just have `&&`, but I feel pressure to accept one of the answers given and I have an inkling that I'm not going to get a better answer. Sorry.