# .gitattributes when cloning repository

Tags: git, attributes, clone, git-clone

Discussing [the propagation of changes to .gitattribute to other repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642692/how-to-make-change-to-gitattributes-take-effect) got me thinking. What if I'm cloning an existing repository that has a .gitattribute?

This file might specify to git which files are to be considered text and which are not. When I clone this repository, does git make sure to read this file and make it effective before checking out files?

I did some experimentation and it seems to work, as I would expect.

Is this documented anywhere?

PS: Whether the .gitattributes file affects itself is not in scope of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I clone [a] repository [in which the commit that I will choose for `git checkout` has a `.gitattributes` file in it], does git make sure to read this file and make it effective before checking out files?

Yes.

> Is this documented anywhere?

Yes, towards the front of [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html):

> When the `.gitattributes` file is missing from the work tree, the path in the index is used as a fall-back. During checkout process, `.gitattributes` in the index is used and then the file in the working tree is used as a fall-back.

There's a bit of un-clarity here in that the index itself is populated semi-simultaneously with the work-tree population—the whole thing is done as if via one big atomic transaction—but in fact, what this means is that Git creates the index<sup>1</sup> from the commit, then uses what's in the index to populate the work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>This "the" index is actually the *new* index, stored in `index.lock`, that will *become* the index later via an atomic rename() operation.  Before any of that happens, though, Git must scan the entire work-tree and verify that the work-tree update is allowed, then do the work-tree update pseudo-atomically, *then* rename the `index.lock` file to `index` to cause the atomic transaction to commit by releasing the lock.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Checking-out and checking-in
>
> These **attributes affect how the contents stored in the repository are copied to the working tree files when commands such as git checkout and git merge run**. They also affect how Git stores the contents you prepare in the working tree in the repository upon git add and git commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_effects